# PHP Array push does not work and return null

Tags: php

I am trying to extract some data from a file. The data is read but when I try to put it in an array, the array_push function is not working and return null. Here`s my code:

```
<?php
$in_file = 'php-files-task.csv';
$new_array = array();


$data = file_get_contents($in_file,true);


    if($data[1] == 'simple' && (int)$data[3] < 10){
        array_push($new_array, $data);
    }

print_r($new_array); //return an empty array
?>
```

If anyone knows how to fill this array and return a proper result?

Comment: file_get_contents does not return an array..

Comment: ok, but the key is to populate the $new_array variable

Comment: the $data is working

Comment: Your `if` condition is going to fail because of what Lars said

Comment: Perhaps you are wanting [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) instead of `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: You mean if I use it the if condition may work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` returns a string, not an array.

You should be calling `fgetcsv()` in a loop.

```
$fd = fopen($in_file, "r");
while ($data = fgetcsv($fd)) {
    if($data[1] == 'simple' && (int)$data[3] < 10){
        array_push($new_array, $data);
    }
}
fclose($fd);
```

This will create a 2-dimensional array containing all the rows of the file that meet the `if` condition.

You can write the new array to another file with a similar loop using `fputcvs()`.

```
$fd = open($out_file, "w");
foreach ($new_array as $row) {
    fputcsv($fd, $row);
}
fclose($fd);
```

You can do the entire thing with a single loop, without using an array.

```
$in_fd = fopen($in_file, "r");
$out_fd = fopen($out_file, "w");
while ($data = fgetcsv($in_fd)) {
    if($data[1] == 'simple' && (int)$data[3] < 10){
        fputcsv($out_fd, $data);
    }
}
fclose($in_fd);
fclose($out_fd);
```

Comment: It worked, but now do you know how can I put the result in a file. Is it gonna be like this:     file_put_contents($out_file, $new_array); the $out_file is already initialized!

Comment: You'll need a similar loop using `fputcsv()`.

Comment: You can't write an array directly to a file. `file_put_contents()` requires a string, not an array.